# Spring Microservice - Account Management

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices

Let's assume a micro service architecture secured using OAuth2. Usually, the `authentication-service` (OAuth2 Authorization Server) is at the same time the `account-service`, that's managing accounts/users.

My current account domain model is more complex! Therefor it makes sense to separate these concerns:

- `account-service`: Responsible for account management (e.g. Uploading profile images, Add a shipping address, ...).
- `authentication-service`: Just responsible for security concerns (e.g. Signing tokens, Sign in, ...).

Well, of course the `authentication-service` needs knowledge about the accounts, managed by another micro service, because it must load principals using a `UserDetailsService`.

**First Approach**

All Account + UserDetails (Credentials) are stored and managed by the `account-service`. Therefor the `UserDetailsService` located at the `authentication-service` calls a RESTful API for loading the user details.

```
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {

        // Call the RESTful API of the account-service instead of common data source
    }
}
```

**Second Approach**

The account details are managed by the `account-service` while all security related user details (Credentials) are stored in a separate data source by the `authentication-service`. This approach requires that every time an account is created, the `account-service` must call the RESTful API of the `authentication-service` to create a appropriate user entry. The challenge is to keep this two services/databases in sync.

Which approach of these (or another) would you recommend for complex account management? Gladly with examples or source code!

Answer (score 0):

In microservices, it happens many times when we have to keep copy of data that we need from a service in another service's database. Like you said that account details shall be present in the authentication service.

You can handle this simply by storing the details of user when he registers in the authentication service and sending a JMS or Kafka message to the account service to keep a copy of it.

This way validating the principal will be easy for you from the incoming JWTs being decoded at the authentication service only.